# select multiple figures in a series using excel visual basic

Tags: vba, selection, shapes

Using excel visual basic, I want to select multiple figures and group them, repeatedly.

My code goes like this:

```
circleCnt = 5

For j = 1 To circleCnt

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, 500, 30, 40, 30).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Height = minWidth + circleWidth * (circleCnt - j + 1)
    Selection.ShapeRange.Width = minWidth + circleWidth * (circleCnt - j + 1)
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft circleWidth / 2 * (j - 1) + circleWidth / 2
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop circleWidth / 2 * (j - 1) + circleWidth / 2

    Next j
```

Yep, it's drawing multiple circles and I'm trying to present my data with these codes. The problem is... my full data makes more than a hundred group of circles and it takes forever to transfer all the circles into the powerpoint

I want to make circles from a sample into a group - and how can I select multiple shape objects? I was thinking like

```
for n = 1 to 5

    select shape #n

    next n
```

but as you can see, this didn't work

Is there any 'cumulative' code for selection? or selecting last object and make them into a group of previously grouped objects?

-I don't want to make 'all circles' into one group - a group for a sample, with multiple samples :)

Comment: ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Oval 2", "Oval 3")).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Group.Select

Comment: Thanks for your comment Siva, but I want to make it into a macro-able code, not one by one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you add the shapes, you need to iterate over all the shapes on the sheet and store the shape names in an array. Using that, you can create a `ShapeRange` object and `Group` the shapes. Here is a code sample:

```
Sub GroupAllShapes()

    Dim arrShapeNames()     As Variant 'must be Variant to work with Shapes.Range()
    Dim shp                 As Shape
    Dim sr                  As ShapeRange
    Dim ws                  As Worksheet
    Dim i                   As Integer

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    ReDim arrShapeNames(ws.Shapes.Count - 1)
    i = 0
    For Each shp In ws.Shapes
        arrShapeNames(i) = shp.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next

    Set sr = ws.Shapes.Range(arrShapeNames)
    sr.Group

    Set sr = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing

End Sub
```

Note: I ported this from some of my C# code and have the arrShapeNames array with a zero-based index. You may need to make it 1-based for VBA.

Comment: Thank you so much Nick, I was not familiar with VBA in excel so had no idea about 'shaperange' and how to use it - this really helped!

Comment: One more thing, is it possible to select few shapes and group them?
say, something like:<br/> <pre>
    for n = 3 to 8<br/>
        sr = ws.Shapes.Range(arrShapeNames(n))<br/>
        next n<br/>
<code>
to make shapes created at 3rd through 8th into one group?
-How can I make line changes? Sorry for the scribbles

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid selecting anything in your code. This makes your code really slow. It's not entirely clear for me what you're trying to do, but try something like this:

```
dim objShape as Shape

for j = 1 To circleCnt

    set objShape = Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, 500, 30, 40, 30)

    With objShape
        .ShapeRange.Height = minWidth + circleWidth * (circleCnt - j + 1)
        .ShapeRange.Width = minWidth + circleWidth * (circleCnt - j + 1)
        .ShapeRange.IncrementLeft circleWidth / 2 * (j - 1) + circleWidth / 2
        .ShapeRange.IncrementTop circleWidth / 2 * (j - 1) + circleWidth / 2
    End With

next

set objShape = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment RobK, and sorry for my limited explanation